# Updated version of yaml file is not getting read

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I am reading a yaml file like so in Python3:

```
def get_file():
    file_name = "file.yml"

    properties_stream = open(file_name, 'r')
    properties_file = yaml.safe_load(properties_stream)
    properties_stream.close()
    print(properties_file)
    return properties_file
```

When I update file.yml by adding keys or deleting all the contents of the file, the "print(properties_file)" statement is still retaining the contents of the yaml file the first time I ran this code.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the file in the current directory (i.e. from where you start the program)? I recommend you either (temporarily) remove the file or use an absolute path to be 100% sure. Maybe you used the correct/recommended extension for YAML file that you are editing (that has been `.yaml` since 2006) and are loading a different file.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Anthon was correct. Turned out I had two folders with the same name in my project directory in a different subdirectory and it was reading from the wrong file.